# Prototype toggle - two instances getting muddled

Tags: javascript, prototypejs

I have two instances that use the toggle(). So in the code there is this link:

```
<a href="#" onClick="$('div1').toggle(); return false;">Completely independent link</a>
```

Followed by a more complex show hide toggle area:

```
<a href="#" onClick="$('showLessInfo').toggle();$('showAllInfo').toggle(); $('showAllInfoLink').toggle(); return false;">Show All</a>
```

And then the reverse of that:

```
<a href="#" onClick="$('showLessInfo').toggle();$('showAllInfo').toggle(); $('showAllInfoLink').toggle(); return false;">Show Less</a>
```

The problem I have is when I toggle the "Show all" link - it renders the "Completely Independent link" unusable. Sometimes it even opens shows/hides #div1?!?

Not really sure what is going on but the two instances are definitely getting muddled up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what is happening is your click event is bubbling up the DOM and it hits other elements - but I can't be sure without seeing more of your HTML structure.

That being said - I would suggest putting everything in separate click observers, it removes the javascript from the HTML, and makes it easier to handle.

For example your 3 links

```
<a href="#" onClick="$('div1').toggle(); return false;">Completely independent link</a>
<a href="#" onClick="$('showLessInfo').toggle();$('showAllInfo').toggle(); $('showAllInfoLink').toggle(); return false;">Show All</a>
<a href="#" onClick="$('showLessInfo').toggle();$('showAllInfo').toggle(); $('showAllInfoLink').toggle(); return false;">Show Less</a>
```

would change to

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="link1">Completely independent link</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="showall">Show All</a>
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id="showless">Show Less</a>
```

and add this in your head or js file or somewhere on your page

```
<script>
    document.observe('dom:loaded', function()
        $('link1').observe('click',function(){
            $('div1').toggle();
        });
        $('showall').observe('click',function(){
            $('showLessInfo').toggle();
            $('showAllInfo').toggle();
            $('showAllInfoLink').toggle();
        });
        $('showless').observe('click',function(){
            $('showLessInfo').toggle();
            $('showAllInfo').toggle();
            $('showAllInfoLink').toggle();
        });
    });

</script>
```

Now for extra bonus, I changed the `href="#"` to `href="javascript:void(0);"` to avoid the need to stop the event.

Answer (score 0):

Dude, your selectors are all messed up.
You can't just use `$('div1')`, because that won't return anything. If it's a class use `$('.div1')` and if it's an id use use `$('#div1')`.

Also maybe avoid writing your handlers inline, it's much harder to read and notice possible errors. Just put all of that in a seperate javascript file.

Comment: Well nevertheless, this might be the reason why it isn't working. Furthermore, it would be helpful if you could reproduce the bug in a jsfiddle. That way it would be easier for people to debug.

Comment: I've just realized that this is actually prototype and not jQuery. So the syntax IS correct. Ill try and change the title.